# Quicksort using 2 pivots

Tags: time-complexity, quicksort

I'm currently preparing for an exam which handles algorithms. I was studying the Quicksort algorithm and it's variations on both the algorithm itself (3-way Quicksort) and partitioning functions (Hoare, Lomuto). I was making some exercises and by looking through exams of previous years, there was a question which really did intrigue me.

I have seen that the time complexity for Quicksort on average is ~1,39nlog(2)n based on comparisons (TILDE NOTATION!). Now the question was what would happen to the time complexity if we would add 2 pivots to the algorithm and 3 partitions. Note that 3-way Quicksort is not what is meant here!

I started trying to explore different possibilities with what would happen and I didn't really come far in my response/thought to the question. I tried re-profiling the prove we saw but this is a probabilistic approach and wouldn't seem fit for this analysis.

Does anyone have any ideas how I might start formulating an answer to this or point me in a direction on how to solve it?

Comment: Still seems like a probability issue. Assume random data, what is the average distribution between the 3 partitions on each partition step, and what percentage of compares will require comparing an element to both pivot values?

Comment: Work out the complexity and you'll see that it changes only by a multiplicative constant.